# in C# when i build my project that have not Error , but when i run my page show the error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ascx

that error is (in my web page):( does not contain a definition for 'GVTable1_RowDeleting' and no extension method 'GVTable1_RowDeleting' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.desktopmodules_friends1_friends1_friends_ascx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))
but my code is:
in ascx:

```
<asp:TableRow><asp:TableCell>
           <asp:GridView ID="GVTable1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" OnRowCommand="GVTable1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="GVTable1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing ="GVTable1_RowEditing">
             <columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name"/>                    
                <asp:BoundField DataField="famil"  HeaderText="famil"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="field"   HeaderText="field"/> 

                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'  onClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
                 <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
            </columns>
</asp:GridView>
        </asp:TableCell>
           </asp:TableRow>
```

now my code for recive argument and delete in cs:

```
 protected void GVTable1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.CommandName)
            {

                case "Delete":
                    Int32 rn = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    string connstring = "Data Source=VAVAN-PC\\SQL2014;Initial Catalog=db1;Persist Security Info=True;User------;
                    string queryDel = "delete from [db1].[dbo].[tbl1] where [db1].[dbo].[tbl1].id = @id;";
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryDel, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                    Fill_grid();
                    break;
```

Comment: show us the code for row delete event "GVTable1_RowDeleting" not "GVTable1_RowCommand", I think you have not added that code and that is what creates this runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

You posted the code for the method `GVTable1_RowCommand`.
The error is related to another method : `GVTable1_RowDeleting`.
You should check if the method `GVTable1_RowDeleting` exists

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your gridview events (rowdeleting) in aspx page rather than ascx.